# LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: gcc, shared-library, makefile

I have tried to link [VINCIA](http://vincia.hepforge.org/) to [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/), but there is a problem related to the location of the shared libraries in my system. Since I have installed all these tools in a directory which is different than `/usr/local/lib/` the Makefile didn't know the location of these libraries.

I have tried to set it manually by this command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

But it doesn't work. Could you please help to fix this problem?

Comment: There is far too little information to realistically help you. What is vincia? what does "link vincia to root" mean? Are you trying to _build_ an application or _run_ it? what "doesn't work" - what actual error messages do you get?

Comment: How did you install ROOT? well try add `/usr/local/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` or to a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` . Then run `sudo ldconfig` to update `ld` cache

Answer (score 1):

Use these specific environment variables:

```
export ROOTLIBDIR=your-root-lib-path
export ROOTINCDIR=your-root-headers-path
```

Reference:

[VINCIA ROOT Interface Linking](http://vincia.hepforge.org/current/htmldoc/VinciaRoot.html#linking)